# C++ template casting on derived classes

Tags: c++

I have 3 class which derived from each other:

```
class Basic{
...
}

class Extended : public Basic{
...
}

class Full : public Extended{
...
}
```

I have a template class which holds 5-5 from this classes:

```
template <class T>
    class group{
    public:
             ...
    private:
        T one, two, three, four, five;
    };

group<Basic> basicGroup;
group<Extended> extendedGroup;
group<Full> fullGroup;
```

Can I easily cast for example fullGroup to basicGroup or extendedGroup to basicGroup? (I just want to cast upward)

Comment: Probably, you need to pass around iterators of those groups, not groups itself. In that case casting wouldn't be required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution would be to create a kind of view-class that can wrap a group, and exposes the individual objects as base-class instances:

```
template <class T>
class group{
public:
    const T & getOne() { return one; }
private:
    T one, two, three, four, five;
};

template <class T, U>
class group_view {
public:
    group_view(group<T> & inner) : innerGroup(inner) {}

    const U & getOne() { return dynamic_cast< const U &>(one); }
private:
    group<T> & innerGroup;
};
```

You could use it like this:

```
group<Full> fullGroup;
group_view<Full, Extended> extendedGroupView(fullGroup);
```

If you extract the public interface of `group` into an abstract base class, you can even use `group_view`s polymorphically.

Answer (score 3):

No, these three types are unrelated, you cannot cast between them.

A good example to understand why is: imagine you have a `std::list<Dog>`, where `Dog` inherits from `Animal`. You may thing it would be natural to consider that the `std::list<Dog>` can be cast into a `std::list<Animal>`; but what would happen with this code?

```
std::list<Dog> dogList;
// ... fill dogList as appropriate
std::list<Animal> animalList = dogList; // Should this be legal?
Animal aml = animalList.get(); // Fine; you get a Dog, which is an Animal
animalList.insert(Cat()); // Aww: you are trying to add a Cat to a Dog list!
```

Comment: Yes and no, there is still a flaw in the type system with this regard because in the perfect OO you would have a ReadOnlyList<Animal> of which a ReadOnlyList<Dog> would be derived. Of course the list would have to be created somewhere where it is writable and ReadOnlyList<Animal> might not have "ownership" of the data but it can be a headache at times that these are unrelated, particularly in hierarchies.

Comment: @CashCow: I don't mean this mechanism cannot be improved, but currently C++ works this way and this is the reason why. The in-out mechanism introduced in C# 4.0, where you can specify covariance or contravariance for each template parameter, is a good improvement. But it does not work in C++.

Comment: Note that my ReadOnlyList doesn't have to be a collection, it just needs to be some way of reading a collection. So it could be const_iterator_range<T>. The co-variance issue I have found to be more of a problem in a factory model where, in the above model, a factory that creates Full in the axample is a type both of a Factory<Basic> and a Factory<Extended> (in some sense) as well as a Factory<Full> because it will create you object of your required type

Answer (score 0):

A class template with a different parameter is considered by the C++ type system to be an entirely different type.  So, a `group<Basic>` is not the same type as a `group<Extended>`, and you cannot safely cast between these two types.

You can only cast upward on individual instances of `Full` or `Extended`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly cast groups like this. What you need to do is either

1. do a generic group class with one-five being *pointers* to Basic
2. Make FullGroup derive from ExtendedGroup, which would derive from basicGroup.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast a container of one type to a container of another type. And in this case group is basically a container...

You need to copy one by one elements.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you don't want to dynamic cast and don't care what type you have underneath. You have an operation you want to perform polymorphically on your base class and you just call it.

Note however though that your group template contains instances of the class, not pointers / shared-pointers to them. Thus you can't add a Full or Extended to a group of a lesser class without slicing it.